# User Permission Tree: How to get there?

Tags: php, mysql, security, permissions, encapsulation

I'm implementing a product stock manage website, witch has many layers of permissions. It has an admin that has all kind of permissions and then level 2, 3, 4, etc... that will have less permitions. But specific users can have special permissions, like for example creating users, or read information about other users.

Consider the following scenario:

```
 * admin inserted user1, user2 and user3.
 * user1 inserted user4 and user5 under his supervision.
 * user1 edited user4's permission so: user4 can see all user5's
   activity, but user5 cannot see user4's activity.
 * user5 inserted user6 and user7 and can see all their activity, but
   user4 cant!
 * user2 is in the same "level" and user1 and user3, but he cant see
   their sublevels activity.
```

How can I make this permission-tree implicit in my database?

Graphical scheme of the permissions tree:

[image]

Comment: Is there something else I could be of assistance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First-off, the table of users would be
{id, username, password, ..., owner}, owner being the user id that created the account
This creates a tree of users.

Then you would need an ACL table in the form
{userid, updatepriviledgeid, deleteuserid, updateuserid, viewid, ..., wholetree, ...}
Each entry would be for a user id in the main table (this is not a primary key)
The rest, e.g. updatepriviledgeid would mean that this user can update the user information. Each record has an associated wholetreeupdtae as a boolean that simplifies whether the user has permission to the whole tree

Comment: Thanks for the input. I'll be updating the original post.